# Proper way to push to char array in ARM Assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, arm

I am passing in a char array `char s[20]` from C to my subroutine in assembly, whose address gets stored in register `x27`.

In assembly, I push to this array `s` like so:

```
str     w0, [x27, w13, SXTW 2]          // s[i] = c
```

This is in a loop, so the address of the char array (`x27`) is used as the base, and my offset is `i`, represented as `w13`. `w0` is the input character I want to push to `s`.

My problem is that the characters are not pushed in the correct indices.

For example, if I give the input `25`, my char array looks like so

```
s[0] = 2 (50)
s[1] =  (0)
s[2] =  (0)
s[3] =  (0)
s[4] = 5 (53)
s[5] =  (0)
s[6] =  (0)
s[7] =  (0)
s[8] =  (0)
...
```

When it should be in this order:

```
s[0] = 2 (50)
s[1] = 5 (53)
s[2] =  (0)
s[3] =  (0)
s[4] =  (0)
s[5] =  (0)
s[6] =  (0)
s[7] =  (0)
s[8] =  (0)
...
```

I think this is because `SXTW 2` is shifting the position of what I add to `x27` by 4. This would work for integers, since they are 4 bytes, but since I am working with chars I am not sure how to do a shift by 1 byte. `SXTW 1` and `SXTW 3` both give me errors.

Is there another method to properly push to this array in assembly?

Comment: Use `strb` (instead of `str`) to store just a single byte.  You also don't want that scaling, `str` with scaling is for storing into integer arrays, not character arrays -- with the difference being the size of the elements (4 bytes vs. 1 byte).

Comment: You have to allocate some space on the stack and then copy the string to that.

Comment: I do `strb  w0, [x27, w13]` and get the error `Error: invalid use of 32-bit register offset at operand 2 -- strb  w0,[x27,w13]'`. So I'm guessing I can't use `w13` as the offset, not sure what to use then since that's what gets incremented.

Comment: I know it's late for you ... one can't use `w13` directly as offset, because it's 32-bit. You could use `strb w0,[x27,w13, SXTW 0]` or if upper 32-bits of x13 are already zero/sign-extended, `strb w0,[x27,x13]`.

Comment: I see I can't edit anymore. Above should be `strb w0,[x27,w13,SXTW]` (or `strb w0,[x27,w13,UXTW]` if not sign-extending).